# Ensuring a NuGet package can only be installed from a specific feed

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipelines job setup to authenticate to a private NuGet feed in Azure Artifacts, and then build my .NET project that relies on a NuGet package in the feed. However, my private package is a pretty common name. How can I ensure that it only installs that specific package from my private feed, and doesn't try to fallback to the NuGet general gallery? I do not want it to pull in an incorrect package that has the same name and version name as my private package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you configure multiple sources/feeds, NuGet will look for a package in all these sources together with no guarantee of where the package will be downloaded from. However, you could make the AzDo artifacts feed as the only configured feed and then upstream other sources from it. This way NuGet will get all packages from the configured AzDo artifacts source and AzDo artifacts will source other packages not available with it from the upstreamed sources in the order defined. More info can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops